# How to generate missing at random (MAR) data for specific "gender" using R from scratch

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I know this is very classic question.
But i'm going to generate missing data at random MAR condition on **Gender** column.
I'm have a simple data says:

```
Gender<-rep(0:1,4, times=3,length=20)
Y<-rep(1:4,2,length = 10)
dat<-cbind(Gender,Y)
```

in which, 0= male and 1= female for the **Gender** column.

How i'm going to generate NA in Y for 20% of female from scratch using R code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, are the instructions for MAR to generate 20 % NA's for female and none for males?

Comment: @bird , there is a mistake..apologize..X is supposed to be the Gender

Comment: @user2974951, yes, only 20% for female and non for males

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
positions <- sample(1:length(Y),length(Y)*.2)
Y[positions] <- NA
```

With this code you generate first the NA samples at some positions, and then, replace the actual positions by NA

Answer (score 1):

You may try :

```
Gender<-rep(0:1,4, times=3,length=20)
Y<-rep(1:4,2,length = 20)
#Get the index for female
female_inds <- Gender == 1
#count 20% of female
Na_inds <- sum(female_inds) * 0.2
#Randomly assign NA to 20% female
Y[sample(which(female_inds), Na_inds)] <- NA
#Combine the data
dat<-cbind(Gender,Y)
dat
```